# Clients face an error running published application with VS2010 (.Net4)

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2010, deployment, clickonce

**Clients face an error while running deployed application**

Host computer need to install .Net 4 before running the app. Here is my application Prerequisites page:

[prerequisites configuration snap shot](https://app.box.com/s/xhakcz4ettlo6ha4wart)

**Publish is successful and client wants to run the application but the result is:**
[File is moved or corrupt. snapshot](https://app.box.com/s/q1i6kvtegr1ddmc8ti9z)

**and here is the error log detail file:**

```
The following properties have been set:
Property: [AdminUser] = true {boolean}
Property: [InstallMode] = SameSite {string}
Property: [ProcessorArchitecture] = AMD64 {string}
Property: [VersionNT] = 6.1.1 {version}
Running checks for package 'Windows Installer 3.1', phase BuildList
The following properties have been set for package 'Windows Installer 3.1':
Running checks for command 'WindowsInstaller3_1\WindowsInstaller-KB893803-v2-x86.exe'
Result of running operator 'VersionGreaterThanOrEqualTo' on property 'VersionMsi' and value '3.1': true
Result of checks for command 'WindowsInstaller3_1\WindowsInstaller-KB893803-v2-x86.exe' is 'Bypass'
'Windows Installer 3.1' RunCheck result: No Install Needed
Running checks for package 'Microsoft .NET Framework 4 (x86 and x64)', phase BuildList
Reading value 'Version' of registry key 'HKLM\Software\Microsoft\NET Framework Setup\NDP\v4\Full'
Unable to read registry value
Not setting value for property 'DotNet40Full_TargetVersion'
The following properties have been set for package 'Microsoft .NET Framework 4 (x86 and x64)':
Running checks for command 'DotNetFX40\dotNetFx40_Full_x86_x64.exe'
Result of running operator 'ValueEqualTo' on property 'InstallMode' and value 'HomeSite': false
Skipping ByPassIf because Property 'DotNet40Full_TargetVersion' was not defined
Result of running operator 'ValueEqualTo' on property 'AdminUser' and value 'false': false
Result of running operator 'VersionLessThan' on property 'VersionNT' and value '5.1.2': false
Result of running operator 'ValueEqualTo' on property 'ProcessorArchitecture' and value 'IA64': false
Result of checks for command 'DotNetFX40\dotNetFx40_Full_x86_x64.exe' is 'Install'
Running checks for command 'DotNetFX40\dotNetFx40_Full_setup.exe'
Result of running operator 'ValueNotEqualTo' on property 'InstallMode' and value 'HomeSite': true
Result of checks for command 'DotNetFX40\dotNetFx40_Full_setup.exe' is 'Bypass'
'Microsoft .NET Framework 4 (x86 and x64)' RunCheck result: Install Needed
Running checks for package 'Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 Report Viewer', phase BuildList
Reading value 'Install' of registry key 'HKLM\Software\Microsoft\DevDiv\VB\Servicing\10.0\ROS'
Read integer value 1
Setting value '1 {int}' for property 'IsViewerInstalled'
The following properties have been set for package 'Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 Report Viewer':
Property: [IsViewerInstalled] = 1 {int}
Running checks for command 'ReportViewer\ReportViewer.exe'
Result of running operator 'ValueExists' on property 'IsViewerInstalled': true
Result of checks for command 'ReportViewer\ReportViewer.exe' is 'Bypass'
'Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 Report Viewer' RunCheck result: No Install Needed
EULA for components 'Microsoft .NET Framework 4 (x86 and x64)' was accepted.
Copying files to temporary directory "C:\Users\ADMINI~1\AppData\Local\Temp\2\VSD1986.tmp\"
Downloading files to "C:\Users\ADMINI~1\AppData\Local\Temp\2\VSD1986.tmp\"
(1/12/2014 11:24:38 AM) Downloading 'DotNetFX40\dotNetFx40_Full_x86_x64.exe' from 'http://10.15.33.176/DotNetFX40/dotNetFx40_Full_x86_x64.exe' to 'C:\Users\ADMINI~1\AppData\Local\Temp\2\VSD1986.tmp\'
Download completed at 1/12/2014 11:24:38 AM
Verifying file integrity of C:\Users\ADMINI~1\AppData\Local\Temp\2\VSD1986.tmp\DotNetFX40\dotNetFx40_Full_x86_x64.exe
Verifying file hash
Error: Setup has detected that the file 'C:\Users\ADMINI~1\AppData\Local\Temp\2\VSD1986.tmp\DotNetFX40\dotNetFx40_Full_x86_x64.exe' has either changed since it was initially published or may be corrupt.
```

**Please Help Me On This!**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After 4 days of googling and trying different solution 
finally I find that because I have both VS2010 and VS2013 on my computer, deploying with vs2010 use .net 4.5 SDK that it has different *PublicKey* then setup can't verify the installation file an installation fail.
**Finally uninstalling .net 4.5 SDK did me a trick.**